# Making LoadLibrary() notice the DLLs in my project and not require their full path

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, azure, loadlibrary

I am writing a web app using Azure in C# and needed to use a C++ DLL, so I added that DLL to my Visual Studio project and used

```
[DllImport("myDLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

However, this DLL starts to crash after I call it too many times.  So, I switched to using `LoadLibrary()` instead as described in this blog entry, which lets me unload and reload the DLL when desired:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jonathanswift/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-net-c/

A drawback with this approach is that (unlike `DllImport()`) it does not recognize that "myDLL" is part of the Visual Studio project; it requires a directory.  This becomes problematic when I try to publish my app to Azure because it can no longer access the DLL.  Is there a good work-around for this?

Comment: _this DLL starts to crash after I call it too many times_, if you don't see this behavior when using `LoadLibrary`, you could have the wrong calling convention (`StdCall` vs. `Cdecl`).

Comment: @Niall it continued to crash after calling it a lot, but I was able to free the library and reload.

Comment: What makes you think that reloading library going to fix crashes? It is either you are using library incorrectly or library has a bug. Reloading library can hardly fix any of these...

Comment: It sounds like the manner in which the library is loaded is not the problem, you have bug that lies elsewhere in the code, either in the global code of the dll, or in the calling convention used.

Comment: The DLL would need to be thread safe if you are calling it from say ASP.Net, weird behaviour related to high use/concurrency can be a symptom of that not being the case.